# How to photograph a footprint on metal?

Tags: metal

I would like to take a photograph of a footprint in some metal. Are there any photography techniques or chemicals that would make the footprint easy to see on a photograph?

It is a piece of glossed metal from a car bonnet, the footprint is actually a from a shoe. I would like to make the print clearer when I take a photo of it, as presently it is barely visible.

CSI fanatics more than welcome on this one!

Comment: Sorry but you need to elaborate on this one. What metal are you talking about and what kind of surface does it have? Is the footprint made up of mud from a shoe or is it grease from a bare foot? When you're talking about chemicals do you want the footprint to be etched to the surface or what did you have in mind?

Comment: @Hugo I have updated my question. As for the chemicals - I am open to ideas; anything to make the shape of the print clearer.

Comment: Could you also show what photos come out with the setup you currently have?

Comment: If the print has some sort of depth (positive or negative) you can try using a very low level light (darkfield) to emphasize it.

Answer (score 1):

I would heavily side-light it.  Since you say it's shiny, most of that light will bounce off and not be seen by the camera.  Other substances on the shiny surface are going to diffuse the light, which will make them show up bright.  The camera should be roughly at a right angle to the surface.

Do this at night or in a dark garage or something so that you can make sure most of the light is hitting the surface at a glancing angle.  You don't want ambient light hitting the surface and reflecting into the camera.

Answer (score 0):

An easier technique is to blow talcum powder on it. The moisture on the print will be visible as powder gets wet.

Answer (score 0):

Spray metal sheet with photo mount. Dust bottom of shoe with talcum powder. Apply shoe. Remove. Voilà!

Comment: He wants to know how to photograph a *existing* print, not how to make one more photographable.